# How to get current gnome keyboard layout from terminal?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-layout

For usage in a bash script, I need to get the gnome keyboard layout the user is currently using. For example if the user sets its keyboard layout to `en-us` , I need a bash command that prints me this.

How can I get that information?

#### Update:

`setxkbmap -query` is unfortunatelly not working. Below is the ouput with the `en` (first command) and the `de` (second command) layout activated. Switching keyboard layout seems to be have some relation with gnome session configuration

```
setxkbmap -query 
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,de
variant:    ,
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,lv3:ralt_switch,grp:alts_toggle

setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,de
variant:    ,
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,lv3:ralt_switch,grp:alts_toggle
```

#### Update2:

```
setxkbmap -print #with en-us layout
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+de:2+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch_for_alts_toggle):1+level3(ralt_switch_for_alts_toggle):2+group(alts_toggle)+level3(ralt_switch)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
setxkbmap -print #after switching to german layout
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+de:2+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch_for_alts_toggle):1+level3(ralt_switch_for_alts_toggle):2+group(alts_toggle)+level3(ralt_switch)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Comment: Sadly it's not bash, but using libxklavier, here's a [python example][1] to do what your asking:



  [1]: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libxklavier/tree/tests/test_gi.py

Comment: <rant>xkb is an undocumented hell! These multiple layout definitions don't work reliably; for me they suddenly switched at random times and after suspend it was randomly determined which of the defined layouts was in effect and -- what's worse -- independently for each keyboard attached. Yes, xkb is actually able to have different layouts for different keyboards but this is not documented anywhere as far as I know and therefore the only thing this feature does is annoy us because we can't control it. xkb, seriously, don't get me started!</rant>

Answer (score 10):

According to a similar question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021111/kde-how-do-i-find-and-switch-current-globar-keyboard-layout-from-cli), the following should do the trick:

```
setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F"+" '{print $2}'
```

I did could not verify it, as I currently have no *nix machine with X available (I'm not home)...

Comment: Running setxkbmap -print returns the following. I don't think this helps the OP.
`xkb_keymap {
 xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
 xkb_types     { include "complete" };
 xkb_compat    { include "complete" };
 xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
 xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};`

Comment: So you currently have "us" layout active? That is what above statement, given your input, would produce as output (only those two letters: "us"). How does it look when you switch to a different layout?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly this is not doing the trick. Both times I get us. I have edited my question to show you the ouput.

Comment: was worth a try. You could try to specify the `-v` parameter (multiple times), which increases verbosity and thus gives more information. Should work for both, `-query` as well as `-print`. As I have no multilang setup, I cannot tell whether it provides the detail you need -- but with 3 times `-v` output here is split into "applied rules" and "keymap". The latter seems to be the complete information, so the first part could have the "currently active part".

Comment: thanks again, but unfortunatelly this did not work out either. The same output before and after the layout change. Independently of the verbosity.

Comment: Sorry. Then I'm out. Good luck to you -- hopefully someone else comes up with something usable...

Comment: The answer on SO is wrong, and it doesn't print the current layout if there are more than one.

Answer (score 6):

### For Ubuntu 17.10 or later

In Ubuntu 17.10, with GNOME, the *current* gsettings value is not changed when you switch input source. Instead there is a *mru-sources* key which lists the **m**ost **r**ecently **u**sed input sources.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources
[('xkb', 'se'), ('xkb', 'us')]
```

The first source in that list is the current one, so a oneliner to get the current layout may look like this:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources | sed -r "s/\S*\s'([^']+).*/\1/"
```

*Please note that this answer does not apply if you use Unity on an Ubuntu 17.10 system. With Unity it keeps working as previously.*

Answer (score 3):

### For Ubuntu 13.04 and lower

You can use [`xkblayout-state`](https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state) tool. See [README.md](https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state/blob/master/README.md) file for description, compilation, installation and usage.

The following command will do exactly what you want:

```
xkblayout-state print "%s"
```

### For Ubuntu 13.10 and higher

Ubuntu 13.10 came with some good improvements in this sense, and you can use the following simple bash function:

```bsh
get_current_xkblayout () {
      current_input_nr=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current | \
          awk '{ print $NF }')
      shift=$(( 2 * ( $current_input_nr + 1 )))
      gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources | tr -d "\',[]()" | \
          awk -v cur="$shift" '{ print $cur }'
}
```

The following commands also works in 13.10:

```
setxkbmap -query | awk -F"(,|[ ]+)" '/layout:/ { print $2 }'
```

or:

```
setxkbmap -print | awk -F"+" '/xkb_symbols/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the terminal, I've run a test changing between 'pt' and 'us', and after every change, I've collected the keyboard layout being used with success:

**Get the active keyboard layout**

```
setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols | awk -F"+" '{print $2}'
```

- Print the configuration: `setxkbmap -print`
- Collect the line that matters: `grep xkb_symbols`
- gets the string after the first "+" sign: `awk -F"+" '{print $2}'`

The output having 'us' layout active is: `us`

---

**Swith between layouts**

```
sudo setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle pt
```

Pass where it reads 'pt', the language code to switch to.

[image]

**Note:** *I'm using Gnome on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem seems to be that users tend to switch between layouts by using task-bar applet. It works if one is switching layout from cmd, but it does not work, if the user switches with the task bar applet.

Comment: @ftiaronsem, You haven't mentioned that part before :) I'll look into it and update my answer if possible!

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
setxkbmap -query
```

This is what you should see

[image]

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer, unfortunatelly this is not working. Here is the ouput (first time with en layout, second with de):

Comment: due to formatting pasted as question edit...

Comment: thanks again for your prompt reply. This is inded what I am seeing, but it does not tell me, whether I selected the german or the american layout. Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

### For Ubuntu 13.10 or Later

**(Not sure if it works in previous releases)**

```
current_layout=gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current | awk '{print $2}'
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources | grep -Po "'[[:alpha:]]+'\)" | sed -ne "s/['|)]//g;$(($current_layout+1))p"
```

To see more option:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.input-sources
```